# Objective-C methods which their only parameter is an NSError object reference, How should I name them?

Tags: objective-c

I was designing a class and I realize that I've got several methods that the only parameter they have is the output parameter for errors. The problem is how should I name this methods, because they can get very confusing. I've been reading the Apple's Code Guidelines and it saids nothing about this. Here is an example:

```
-(BOOL)loginError(NSError **) anError;

-(BOOL)loginWithUsername:(NSString *)aUsername password:(NSString *)aPassword error:(NSError **) anError;
```

The second one is very clear but the first one seems to be very confusing to me.

What do you think?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apple use names such as

```
- (BOOL) saveValuesAndReturnError:(NSError **) error;
```

So, perhaps:

```
- (BOOL) loginAndReturnError:(NSError **) error;
```